# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un error 1054 de Mysql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente código:

```sql
DELETE FROM posts WHERE $id = '3'
```

Pero cuando se ejecuta, recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'
>
> DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `$id` = '3'
>
> Filename: C:/wamp/www/ciblog/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

¿Cómo puedo solucionar un error 1054 de Mysql?

Comment: Los nombres con `$` se usan en PHP, para MySQL debería ser por ejemplo: `DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '3'` o bien, si la columna `id` es numérica: `DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = 3` .

Comment: dice que la columna '$id' no existe, debe ser 'id'. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer la consulta esta mal construida.
Pienso yo que deberia ser algo asi:

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $id
```

Donde $id es igual a 3 ó no usar variables y dejarlo explicito:

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '3'
```

Pero va a depender de

Answer (score 1):

EL error  1054 se genera porque el campo no existe, lo mas comun es que tengas, mal escrito el nombre, al realizar tu consulta, recomiendo que lo copies y pegues tal cual esta en la columna de tu base de datos.

En este caso en particular el error es que cuando estas haciendo tu consulta tienes que escribir la sintaxis como si fuera MYSQL y no como en PHP es decir en ves de poner

```
$id
```

debes poner solo

```
id
```

Quedando por ejemplo así

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi código con el error

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `tienda_online`.`inventario` SET `nombrep` = $nop WHERE (`idinventario` = $id);");
```

y este es mi código con la solución

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `tienda_online`.`inventario` SET `nombrep` = '$nop' WHERE (`idinventario` = '$id');");
```

consiste en básicamente agregar las comillas simples, en mi caso que utilizo ajax.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: no olvides hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y leer [answer].

Comment: Si esta respuesta es la que te sirvió, márcala como la correcta. No olvides puntuar las demás respuestas que son útiles y de ayuda.